# How to retrieve 2 values at a time from a map - in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinates, subscript, alternating

This is a Python 2.x function for handling sequences with x, y coordinates; please note that argument ints is of type map:

```
def IntsToPoints(ints):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(ints), 2):
        result.append(Point(ints[i], ints[i+1]))
    return result
```

I'm converting it to Python 3.x and the map object is no longer subscriptable. This is how I have solved it for the meantime:

```
def IntsToPoints(ints):
    result = []
    for i, myint in zip(range(len(list(ints))), ints):
        if i%2 == 0: x = myint
        else: result.append(Point(x, myint))
    return result
```

Is there anyone who has a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic python idiom is `zip(*[iter(...)]*2)`, which works with any iterable:

```
points = [Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(*[iter(ints)] * 2)]
```

Since you're passing `map`, which is already an iterator, you can omit `iter`:

```
points = [Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(*[ints] * 2)]
```

or, simpler,

```
points = [Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(ints, ints)]
```

but I'd leave it in to keep the function more generic (some day you might want to pass a `list` instead of a `map`).

Comment: Yes, you need to leave the iter in! The last 2 expressions result in points with the same values for x and y. That was not the idea!

Comment: @Dobedani: no, they don't, provided `ints` is actually a generator (e.g. a map) and not a list